# Login Button's facebook in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook-sdk-4.0

I've tryied to add this login button, after using the facebook-sdk of course:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

eclipse doesn't show me a button and the emulator doesn't work with this button. thank-you..

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the button shown in emulator?

Comment: Shadow, what do you mean by removing login? I need this login button... 
Harry, the emulator does not even work, because I've only added this button. before that it worked.

Comment: see my answer and check whether it works.

Comment: i am saying it's "com.facebook.widget.LoginButton" and not com.facebook."login".widget.LoginButton. the package name reference is wrong. remove that login..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line and moreover it's  com.facebook.widget.LoginButton and not   com.facebook.widget.login.LoginButton.

```
 xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"


      <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
            xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            fb:login_text="Sign in with Facebook" />
```

Comment: listen, I don't have the widget, or the loginbutton, when im trying to use them it doesn't let me like it doesn't exist. only these shown me: [link](http://s10.postimg.org/fy5fho14p/image.png)